# Why dont my buttons work in my pyqt5 GUI?

Tags: python, oop, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

When I made a GUI i used different classes to construct the main UI Screen.
My code has the following structure:

[image]

This is the GUI itself:

[image: UI Screen]

The bottum_buttons.py creates the 3 buttons at the buttom. This is the code that is inside bottum_buttons.py:

```
import Advanced_window
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from datetime import datetime
import calendar
import sys

class bottum_buttons(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        # Create Layout
        self.bottum_box = QHBoxLayout()

        # Creating Buttons
        self.cancel_button = QPushButton("Cancel")
        self.run_button = QPushButton("Run")
        self.advanced_button = QPushButton("Advancend Options")

        self.add_items_to_layout()
        self.create_button_functions()

    def add_items_to_layout(self):
        self.bottum_box.addWidget(self.cancel_button)
        self.bottum_box.addWidget(self.run_button)
        self.bottum_box.addWidget(self.advanced_button)

    def create_button_functions(self):
        self.cancel_button.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.advanced_button.clicked.connect(Advanced_window.advancedwindows)

    def return_bottum_buttons(self):
        return self.bottum_box
```

My code that actually constructs the GUI is inside main_screen.py.
The following code is inside this file:

```
from Ui_Elements import option_box
from Ui_Elements import path_box
from Ui_Elements import bottum_buttons
from Ui_Elements import command_output
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from datetime import datetime
import calendar
import sys


class main_screen(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Robo Tool")
        self.main_frame = QVBoxLayout()

        # Get UI Elements
        path_ui = path_box.path_box()
        option_ui = option_box.option_box()
        command_ui = command_output.command_box()
        bottum_ui = bottum_buttons.bottum_buttons()

        self.path = path_ui.return_path_box()
        self.option_box = option_ui.return_options_box()
        self.command_output = command_ui.return_command_box()
        self.bottum_buttons = bottum_ui.return_bottum_buttons()

        self.setLayout(self.add_item_to_frame(self.main_frame))

    def add_item_to_frame(self, main_frame):
        main_frame.addLayout(self.path)
        main_frame.addLayout(self.option_box)
        main_frame.addLayout(self.command_output)
        main_frame.addLayout(self.bottum_buttons)
        return main_frame

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
dialog = main_screen()
dialog.show()
app.exec_()
```

Now the problem is. When i start the main_screen.py the GUI shows up as the picture provided. But the buttons don't work. I dont get any error message. They're still clickable but they dont run the command i provided. Can somebody please help me out.

Comment: I suppose that with "buttom" and "bottum", you mean "bottom". Just to clarify, as saying that you have a file named "bottum_buttons that creates buttons at bottum" is a bit of a tongue-twister :-)

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. yeah you're right english also isn't my native language so sometimes i make a grammatical error whoops.. Yeah it is a real tong twister. Maybe refactor it to something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what `Advanced_window.advancedwindows()` is supposed to do, but your cancel button is connected to `bottom_buttons.close`, not to `main_screen.close` which I assume is what you want. Since `bottom_buttons` has no knowledge in advance about which window is supposed to be closed, you can't really connect the button to the close method of a predefined widget. What you could do however is to use `self.window().close()` instead which would close the next-level ancestor widget of `bottom_buttons` that has a window. For this, you would need to set the layout of `bottom_bottuns` to `self.bottom_box` and add the whole widget to the layout of `main_screen` rather than just the layout.

This would mean that you would get something like this for `bottom_buttons`:

```
class bottum_buttons(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        
        .... as before ....

        # set bottom_box as layout of self
        self.setLayout(self.bottom_box)

    ....

    def create_button_functions(self):
        # connect cancel button to close method of top level ancestor widget
        self.cancel_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.window().close())
        ....
```

And for `main_screen`:

```
class main_screen(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        .... as before ....

        # set self.bottom_buttons to bottom_buttons widget rather than the layout
        self.bottum_buttons = bottum_ui

        self.setLayout(self.add_item_to_frame(self.main_frame))

    def add_item_to_frame(self, main_frame):
        ...
        # add bottom_buttons widget to the layout.
        main_frame.addWidget(self.bottum_bottons)
        return main_frame
```

Comment: Thanks man that worked for me. Sorry for the bad english and bad code. I'm still learning a lot about coding. Thanks for taking the time. About the Advanced_window.advancedwindow that was meant that when the button is clicked it needed to create a instnace of the advancedwindow class

Comment: It is a class within the Advanced_window.py. But i dont really now how to do that either